# I was making a clock in python and i got an error

Tags: python, tkinter, time

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

from time import strftime

root = Tk()
root.title('Clock')

def time():
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %P')
    label.config(text=string)
    label.after(1000, time)

label = Label(root, font=("ds-digital", 80), background="black", foreground="cyan")
label.pack(anchor='center')
time()

mainloop()
```

I got this error

```
File "c:\Users\david\OneDrive\Desktop\practice projects\clock.py", line 16, in <module>
    time()
  File "c:\Users\david\OneDrive\Desktop\practice projects\clock.py", line 10, in time
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %P')
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Comment: Your first stop should have been the documentation for `time.strftime`, which would have shown you the problem.

Comment: `%P` is not supported in Windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

Try lower case P:

```python
string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
```

but this is 24 hour base so you might not need AM or PM. If you want 12 Hour based, use:

```python
string = strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
```

Docs:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

Comment: yea thanks i got it

Comment: Glad it works :) Please consider accepting solution if it helped

Comment: @Matt, Consider making text into hyperlink rather than posting the full link, like so [docs](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)

Comment: Also it is better to post document on [`strftime()` on official site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error while following a youtube tutorial for it as a beginner and for me the fix was simple making the P in my string lowercase. ('%H:%M:%S %p')